# Does SSRS store ad-hoc report history

Tags: reporting-services

I've learned enough about SSRS to know that you can take snapshots and view a history of a scheduled report that is great.

How we use it here is that we publish many reports and users run them when they want.  Does SSRS store when users logged in and what reports they ran?

Unfortuntely, I don't have database access to the report services database to check myself, hence why I'm asking this question.

We are running SQL Server 2008 (not R2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It records what reports have been run - in the ExecutionLog table in the reporting services database.

Without query access to the reporting services database, this is unlikely to be useful to you.

Comment: For SSRS 2008 (not R2), there is a view called ExecutionLog2 which displays more than enough information.  Thanks Mark for more or less answering my question.